# I have a .car file for websphere application server7, can I make few changes in it so that it runs in WAS9 too?

Tags: java, web, websphere

I have a `.car` file for websphere application server7, I want to reuse the same `.car` file for WAS9, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Config archives are not really meant for migration from one release of WebSphere Application Server to another, you should use the [IBM WebSphere Migration Tools](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mw-1701-was-migration/index.html) to do that.